# Finding and replacing strings with accented characters using ArcPy UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have a number of feature classes in which some records in the attribute tables need updating with new information.  However the strings to replace aren't found in the UpdateCursor due to the presence of accented characters.  I've run the same search on the table and just removed the accented e (é) from both the record and the search string and the string is found and replaced correctly.

```
# For each row, evaluate the PRESENCE field (index position 
# of 0), 
# and update with new value if the record reads
# "Présence n'est pas probable"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, inputField) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "Présence n'est pas probable":
            row[0] = "Non probable"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            pass
```

How does one search for a string with accented characters?

Comment: Saw other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325753/how-to-find-accented-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Also this with regex which should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847976/python-regex-to-find-accented-words

Answer (score 1):

As commented you can remove the accents using [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). I have not tried the code but I think it should work:

```
import unicodedata, arcpy

def remove_accents(input_str):
    #From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, inputField) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if remove_accents(row[0]) == remove_accents("Présence n'est pas probable"):
            row[0] = "Non probable"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            pass
```